# How to take Screenshots of Device screens outside my own app on a rooted device?

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take screenshots of my device screens, that is rooted,  am using following code:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("/system/bin/screencap -p " + path + "; \n");
```

This code works well on Motorola Zoom,as Zoom has screencap under /system/bin/screencap path,but on huawei ascend which is android 2.3.6, there is no screencap file in system/bin so i m unable to take screen shots on huawei.
Please suggest me ,how can i take screenshots on my Huawei device.

Answer (score 0):

If these devices are based around the same CPU family you could try pulling the screencap binary from your Zoom and pushing it to your Ascend.

Alternatively, you could build the screencap utility yourself (or some program that does the same thing). It's [open source after all](https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=cmds/screencap;h=b5652d81a046c8c1f05e9107d90ff7cd137091ab;hb=refs/heads/jb_mr1).

Comment: I have done this, now it captures image but only notification bar visible ,rest image is blank.i m unable to understand ,please help.

Comment: Also if i open notification bar and then capture image then fully visible image will be captured,means only notification bar's image is visible. i m unable to understand ,please help.